# How do you upgrade a SQL Express Database to SQL Server Workgroup or Standard?

Tags: sql-server-2005, upgrade, sql-server-express

I have a website that was originally developed using a SQL Express database in the App_Data folder. Now I need to take upgrade it, without loosing any data, to SQL Server 2005 Workgroup or Standard.

Is there a guide on how to properly upgrade by Microsoft or another source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When installing Workgroup or Standard it will upgrade the database server and the databases at the same time. Make sure you have a backup of your database (just in case). You can always backup the database and restore it to Workgroup or Standard as well.

Here's a guide:
http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=55